# How to send data from libgdx project to web?

Tags: libgdx, http

I would like to work on moving the json data from libgdx to my web server, but I am not sure how to do it. The method below was created by referring to libgdx's documentation.

```
private void httpPostJson(){
    final Json json = new Json();
    final String requestJson = json.toJson(requestObject);
    Net.HttpRequest request = new Net.HttpRequest("POST");
    final String url = "http://localhost:8080/data";
    request.setUrl(url);
    request.setContent(requestJson);

    request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    Gdx.net.sendHttpRequest(request, new Net.HttpResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void handleHttpResponse(Net.HttpResponse httpResponse) {
            String responseJson = httpResponse.getResultAsString();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            data = gson.fromJson(responseJson, Person.class);
            //'Person' is just sample class. data is class Person's object.
            data.StoreData("",1);//successed to receive json data from web server.
            //StoreData is just getter method.
        }

        @Override
        public void failed(Throwable t) {
            Gdx.app.log("failed!");
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelled() {
            Gdx.app.log("cancelled!");
        }
    });
}
```

It is possible to receive data transmitted from a web server.
But, this method can't send data to web server. 
Can you tell me how to move data from libgdx project to web server?

Comment: "But, this method can't send data to web server" - just what do you think that [setContent](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Net.HttpRequest.html#setContent-java.io.InputStream-long-) call is doing? It's up to your server-side process to decide what to do with the content you've provided in your POST request. How have you tried acting on the sent data in your server process so far?

Comment: sorry about my wrong expression because of my low english ability. i just wonder about how to send data to web. I think 'setContent' function is to declare the format of the data received. if i wrong, teach me plz ㅠ0ㅠ.

Comment: You are wrong. SetContent can accept arbitrary blobs of data to send to the server, like the JSON request object you're using here.